# Modifying xml via regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following XML String:

```
 <asd1:content></asd1:content>
```

The namespace prefix asd1 could be different at different places in the XML file.

I want to modify it to :

```
 <asd1:content>*</asd1:content>
```

I am trying to do it via regex as follows:

```
myString.replaceAll("<.*:content></.*:content>","replacement text");
```

The problem is that I don,t want to lose the namespace prefix. What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1065197

Comment: what you are looking for is an xml parser.  it handles all that crazy namespace stuff automatically.

Comment: I am already using xmlunit for comparison but the stupid thing gives error in case of empty text nodes.Thats why I am trying to replace empty textnodes with dummy text before performing comparison

Comment: post an example of the code you want to replace and the desired output.

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: "I have the following XML String" - no you don't, that's not well-formed XML (colon in the start tag, dot in the end tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you've 2 typos:

`cotent` instead of `content`
`replaceAlll` instead of `replaceAll`

If you still need a regex, you can use:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?ism)<(.*?):content></(.*?)\\.content>", "<$1:content>*</$2.content>");
```

Comment: That's 3 typo's if you include the end tag where ':' is replaced with '.': `</asd1.content>`.